# How I can find t to maximize this Q-function?

Tags: normal-distribution, optimization, gaussian-process, expectation-maximization

I am wondering Q is a Q-function, and 
$Y = Q(\frac{t-1}{0.0894})(1-Q(\frac{t}{0.0894}))$

How can I find $t$ such that it maximizes $Y$?

Comment: Is $Q$ the [Normal survival function?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) (It's easy to maximize anything of the form $q(1-q)$ for $0\le q\le 1$: set $q=1/2$, the vertex of that parabola.  So you're asking how to find $t$ such that $Q((t-1)/0.0894)=1/2$.  When $Q$ is the Normal survival funtion that's very simple algebra indeed, since $Q(x)=1/2$ only when $x=0,$ immediately leading to $t-1=-t$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get 1/2

There are a couple ways to do this.  The easiest is to plot it in Matlab or other math package.

[image]

The other way is to take the derivative and solve equal to 0.  The algebra is pretty rough, but you'll eventually get to $e^{(-(t-1)^2/2)}=e^{(-t^2/2)} $ thus -2t+1=0